# Is Android backup no longer able to back up SMS and MMS for G Suite users?

Tags: backup, sms, google-backup, android-13, android-14

I am using G Suite legacy and recently around October 2023, I discovered that my SMS and MMS were not backed up in the Android backup provided by Google One.

On a Gmail account, backups work normally including backing up SMS and MMS. But in my G Suite account, SMS and MMS are only reserved 1.0 MB of the supposed 290 MB.

Has anyone experienced something similar and what is the solution?